# Learn acoustic guitar using software

Tags: windows, software-rec, music

Inspired by this question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/58813/software-to-learn-playing-music) , Is there any such kind of software to learn guitar ? (Please note : I am not looking for any tutorial , just software )

Preferably Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: You can't learn an instrument like a Guitar just by software, why would one need software that would be very limited if you have a site like http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/ with tons of articles, tutorials, songs, a community and more... The best way to learn playing a guitar would be to practice playing songs or practicing techniques. If you rather want to learn to read notes, see the other question and search or buy some music sheets... ;-)

Comment: Ryan seems to have found something, but again, it are tabs like the site I mentioned.

Comment: I looked for something like this when I got frustrated with my repeated failed attempts at getting any good at guitar.  I wanted something like rockband where i could hook my guitar into my computer and play along with.  Unfortunately I came up empty and just bought an easy beatles chord book, which finally got me past the beginner stage :)

Comment: I personally use tux-guitar (cross-platform tab reader) or songsterr (online tab reader) to learn songs (Fingerstyle/classical). It helps because I don't need to be able to read the sheet music to decipher rhythm. It won't help you if you are a very beginning beginner though.
Also, solfege is a linux program to train ear that I used to use.

Comment: It's not a good idea learning guitar or any other musical instruments using the software. Softwares will give you limited info and you will have no option to clarify any confusion or question. The best way of learning an instrument is to practice with that instrument. It is better if you take [lessons](https://youtu.be/KlIbHpmFEUM) from a guitarist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Some reviews of software you can buy...](http://guitar-lesson-software-review.toptenreviews.com/)
- [Free stuff (30-day trial, at least)](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/titles/guitar-teaching.htm)

Comment: I merged your answers together for you.